# Issue while trying to post listing in Ebay

Tags: xml, ebay-api, listings

**About**
I am trying to post Listing in Ebay Trading API. As we can see that there is brand info mentioned as per the Ebay API documentation here: https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/AddItem.html#Input

but still it gives below error. Am I missing anything in the XML?

**Error details**

> The item specific Brand is missing. Add Brand to this listing, enter a
> valid value, and then try again.

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddItemRequest
    xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>My Token</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <Item>
        <Brand>iPhone 12 Pro Max</Brand>
        <BuyerProtection>ItemIneligible</BuyerProtection>
        <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
        <Title>Apple iPhone 12 Pro Max 256GB Pacific Blue Unlocked - Excellent Condition</Title>
        <Description>This listing is for a gently used Apple iPhone 12 Pro Max in the Pacific Blue color variant. The phone is unlocked and has a storage capacity of 256GB, providing ample space for your apps, photos, and videos.The phone has been well-maintained and is in excellent condition with minimal signs of wear. It has been tested and verified to be fully functional. The screen is free of scratches or cracks, and the body of the phone may have minor cosmetic imperfections consistent with normal use.Included with the phone are the original box and accessories, including the charging cable and adapter. The phone will be securely packaged for shipping.</Description>
        <PictureDetails>
            <GalleryType>Gallery</GalleryType>
            <PhotoDisplay>PicturePack</PhotoDisplay>
            <PictureURL>https://www.pexels.com/photo/bridge-near-waterfall-358457/</PictureURL>
            <ExternalPictureURL>https://www.pexels.com/photo/bridge-near-waterfall-358457/</ExternalPictureURL>
        </PictureDetails>
        <ReturnPolicy>
            <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
            <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
            <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
            <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
        </ReturnPolicy>
        <PostalCode>33181</PostalCode>
        <ShippingDetails>
            <CalculatedShippingRate>
                <OriginatingPostalCode>33181</OriginatingPostalCode>
                <PackagingHandlingCosts currencyID="USD">0.0</PackagingHandlingCosts>
            </CalculatedShippingRate>
            <ShippingServiceOptions>
                <ShippingService>UPSGround</ShippingService>
                <ShippingServicePriority>2</ShippingServicePriority>
            </ShippingServiceOptions>
        </ShippingDetails>
        <ProductListingDetails>
            <BrandMPN>
                <Brand>iPhone 12 Pro Max</Brand>
                <MPN>MGDC3LLA</MPN>
            </BrandMPN>
            <Brand>iPhone 12 Pro Max</Brand>
            <IncludeeBayProductDetails>false</IncludeeBayProductDetails>
        </ProductListingDetails>
        <ShippingPackageDetails>
            <ShippingPackage>USPSLargePack</ShippingPackage>
            <WeightMajor unit="lbs">6</WeightMajor>
            <WeightMinor unit="oz">0</WeightMinor>
        </ShippingPackageDetails>
        <Location>San Jose</Location>
        <PrimaryCategory>
            <CategoryID>137865</CategoryID>
        </PrimaryCategory>
        <StartPrice>10.00</StartPrice>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
        <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
        <ItemSpecifics>
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>iPhone 12 Pro Max</Name>
                <Value>MGDC3LLA</Value>
            </NameValueList>
        </ItemSpecifics>
    </Item>
</AddItemRequest>
```

**Error Details**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddItemResponse
    xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2024-04-02T19:44:39.536Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <Errors>
        <ShortMessage>The item specific Brand is missing.</ShortMessage>
        <LongMessage>The item specific Brand is missing. Add Brand to this listing, enter a valid value, and then try again.</LongMessage>
        <ErrorCode>21919303</ErrorCode>
        <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
        <ErrorParameters ParamID="0">
            <Value>The item specific Brand is missing.</Value>
        </ErrorParameters>
        <ErrorParameters ParamID="1">
            <Value>The item specific Brand is missing. Add Brand to this listing, enter a valid value, and then try again.</Value>
        </ErrorParameters>
        <ErrorParameters ParamID="2">
            <Value>Brand</Value>
        </ErrorParameters>
        <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Version>1353</Version>
    <Build>E1353_UNI_API5_19110890_R1</Build>
</AddItemResponse>
```

Comment: This is confusing.  You have a tag <Brand> which is not in the sample.  Try removing. 
 Brand has two meanings 1) The manufactures brand 2) "Brand New".  It looks like the manufacture brand is OK, but it could be the brand is not in database or the forward slash is causing an issue. "Brand New" is Condition Code 1000.  You have condition 1000, but no descriptor which may be causing issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/AddItem.html#Request.Item.ProductListingDetails.BrandMPN):

> "Both Brand and MPN should be specified if the BrandMPN container is used, or an error may occur."

In other words, the product must have both the brand and MPN.

### Edit:

The *brand* might need to be **`Apple`**.  Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddItemRequest
    xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>My Token</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <Item>
        <BuyerProtection>ItemIneligible</BuyerProtection>
        <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
        <Title>Apple iPhone 12 Pro Max 256GB Pacific Blue Unlocked - Excellent Condition</Title>
        <Description>This listing is for a gently used Apple iPhone 12 Pro Max in the Pacific Blue color variant. The phone is unlocked and has a storage capacity of 256GB, providing ample space for your apps, photos, and videos.The phone has been well-maintained and is in excellent condition with minimal signs of wear. It has been tested and verified to be fully functional. The screen is free of scratches or cracks, and the body of the phone may have minor cosmetic imperfections consistent with normal use.Included with the phone are the original box and accessories, including the charging cable and adapter. The phone will be securely packaged for shipping.</Description>
        <PictureDetails>
            <GalleryType>Gallery</GalleryType>
            <PhotoDisplay>PicturePack</PhotoDisplay>
            <PictureURL>https://www.pexels.com/photo/bridge-near-waterfall-358457/</PictureURL>
            <ExternalPictureURL>https://www.pexels.com/photo/bridge-near-waterfall-358457/</ExternalPictureURL>
        </PictureDetails>
        <ReturnPolicy>
            <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
            <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
            <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
            <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
        </ReturnPolicy>
        <PostalCode>33181</PostalCode>
        <ShippingDetails>
            <CalculatedShippingRate>
                <OriginatingPostalCode>33181</OriginatingPostalCode>
                <PackagingHandlingCosts currencyID="USD">0.0</PackagingHandlingCosts>
            </CalculatedShippingRate>
            <ShippingServiceOptions>
                <ShippingService>UPSGround</ShippingService>
                <ShippingServicePriority>2</ShippingServicePriority>
            </ShippingServiceOptions>
        </ShippingDetails>
        <ProductListingDetails>
            <BrandMPN>
                <Brand>Apple</Brand>
                <MPN>MGDC3LLA</MPN>
            </BrandMPN>
            <IncludeeBayProductDetails>false</IncludeeBayProductDetails>
        </ProductListingDetails>
        <ShippingPackageDetails>
            <ShippingPackage>USPSLargePack</ShippingPackage>
            <WeightMajor unit="lbs">6</WeightMajor>
            <WeightMinor unit="oz">0</WeightMinor>
        </ShippingPackageDetails>
        <Location>San Jose</Location>
        <PrimaryCategory>
            <CategoryID>137865</CategoryID>
        </PrimaryCategory>
        <StartPrice>10.00</StartPrice>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Country>US</Country>
        <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
        <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
    </Item>
</AddItemRequest>
```

Comment: I have updated the xml in question with error details. Still coming same error

Answer (score 0):

> The item specific Brand is missing

I do see ["ItemSpecifics" in the documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/AddItem.html#Request.Item.ItemSpecifics)

So eBay might expect [item specifics](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/user-guides/static/trading-user-guide/include-item-specifics.html), like the brand, to be tucked inside that specific part of the XML `<ItemSpecifics>`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  ...
  <Item>
    ...
    <ItemSpecifics>
      <NameValueList>
        <Name>Brand</Name>
        <Value>iPhone 12 Pro Max</Value>
      </NameValueList>
    </ItemSpecifics>
    ...
  </Item>
</AddItemRequest>
```

By wrapping your brand info inside `<ItemSpecifics>` and `<NameValueList>`, eBay should know exactly where to find the brand name you are trying to add.

---

The error you are see indicates a mismatch between what eBay expects for the "`Brand`" item specific and what is being provided in your XML.
In your XML under `<ItemSpecifics>`, you have tried to specify the brand with:

```xml
<ItemSpecifics>
    <NameValueList>
        <Name>iPhone 12 Pro Max</Name>
        <Value>MGDC3LLA</Value>
    </NameValueList>
</ItemSpecifics>
```

However, this structure is incorrect for what eBay expects. The `<Name>` should be "`Brand`", and the `<Value>` should be the actual brand of the item (e.g., "`Apple`"), not the model or the MPN (Manufacturer Part Number).

```xml
<ItemSpecifics>
    <NameValueList>
        <Name>Brand</Name>
        <Value>Apple</Value>
    </NameValueList>
    <!-- Other specifics like Model, MPN, etc. -->
</ItemSpecifics>
```

Make sure to remove or correct the `<Brand>` elements outside of `<ItemSpecifics>` that are not recognized by the eBay API.

Your XML would be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    ...
    <Item>
        ...
        <Title>Apple iPhone 12 Pro Max 256GB Pacific Blue Unlocked - Excellent Condition</Title>
        <Description>That listing is for a gently used Apple iPhone 12 Pro Max...</Description>
        ...
        <ItemSpecifics>
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>Brand</Name>
                <Value>Apple</Value>
            </NameValueList>
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>Model</Name>
                <Value>iPhone 12 Pro Max</Value>
            </NameValueList>
            <!-- Include other specifics as needed, such as MPN -->
        </ItemSpecifics>
        ...
    </Item>
</AddItemRequest>
```

---

From "[Common eBay Listing Errors Explained](http://support.channelgrabber.com/en/articles/1356762-common-ebay-listing-errors-explained)" (written by [Clare Cormican](https://www.linkedin.com/in/clarecormican), and [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78240314/issue-while-trying-to-post-listing-in-ebay?noredirect=1#comment137977710_78240314) by [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng)), eBay requires a "Brand" to be specified in your item specifics: when you do not have a brand is to use "`Unbranded`" in the Brand field of the item specifics. That is a common practice for items that do not have a specific brand associated with them or when the brand is not recognized by eBay's catalog.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>My Token</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <Item>
        <!-- Other item details omitted for brevity -->
        <ItemSpecifics>
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>Brand</Name>
                <Value>Unbranded</Value>
            </NameValueList>
            <!-- Other specifics, such as Model, MPN -->
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>Model</Name>
                <Value>iPhone 12 Pro Max</Value>
            </NameValueList>
            <NameValueList>
                <Name>MPN</Name>
                <Value>MGDC3LLA</Value>
            </NameValueList>
        </ItemSpecifics>
        <!-- More item details -->
    </Item>
</AddItemRequest>
```

Still, considering that the item you are listing is an Apple iPhone, it is clear that "`Apple`" should be the correct brand, and "`Unbranded`" should not be appropriate in this context.

For branded items like an iPhone, make sure the brand "`Apple`" is clearly stated in the `<ItemSpecifics>` section, as previously shown.